# Get-ChildItem returning first letter of directory when only one subdirectory

Tags: powershell

So this is weird or maybe not. ???
In the folder there might be multiple directories consisting of 2 characters, will say B0 and DE. When I run the command below with both directories in there it returns C:\temp1\B0, if I remove the B0 directory it returns c:\temp1\D. If instead I remove DE it will return c:\temp1\B0 . I did a number of tests with different subdirectory names and when ever there was at least two subfolders it would return the entire subfolder name but when there is only one directory left it only returns the first character of the remaining folder. ???

```
$Folder = "c:\temp1\"
$EMLpath = gci $Folder -name 
$EMLpath = $EMLpath[0]
$EMLpath = "$Folder$EMLpath"
$EMLpath
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `$EMLpath = @(gci $Folder -name)` so `[0]` is always the first element of an array :)

Comment: To complement @SantiagoSquarzon's helpful comment, PowerShell cmdlets output single objects instead of arrays if the output is only a single item. So in your case `$EMLpath` will be of type `string` instead of `string[]`. Test for yourself: `$EMLpath.GetType().Name`

Comment: I understand. 
I don't understand how to close this question. There is no option to select Santiago's answer as the chosen answer, so I guess I answer it myself.  ???

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Santiago and zett42 this works:

```
$Folder = "c:\temp1\"
$EMLpath = @(gci $Folder -name)
$EMLpath = $EMLpath[0]
$EMLpath = "$Folder$EMLpath"
$EMLpath
```

Comment: Comments can't be accepted as answers, you can answer your own question as you've just done now and then [click the tick to accept your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/962245)